# "A regular element of a ring cannot be in any of its proper ideals"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $(R, +, \times, 0, 1)$ be a ring where $0$ is the identity of $+$ and $1$ is the identity of $\times$.

A **regular element** of a R is an element such that it is neither a left-divisor, or a right divisor of $0$. That is, suppose $a$ is a regular element of $R$, then for any $x \in R$: 
$$ a \times x \neq 0$$
$$ x \times a \neq 0$$

An **ideal** $I$ is such that $(I, +)$ is a sub-group of $(R, +)$, and for any $x \in R$, if $y \in I$, then $y \times x \in Y$. A **proper ideal** is an ideal $I$ of $R$ such that $I \neq R$.

I read the following in an [article](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Davis.pdf) I am trying to understand:

[image]

It *seems* that I want to show that if $a$ is regular, then $a \not\in I$, where $I$ is a proper ideal?

I am using Wikipedia as the source of my definitions, so what I have written about is my (mis)interpretation of Wikipedia's definitions.

Comment: Next time, please link [the source](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Davis.pdf). Given that the author clarifies that nonregular elements are "those finite numbers without finite multiplicative inverses," I think by regular elements they mean units, or possibly some variant of a unit that deals with infinitesimals.

Comment: @André3000 ok, will do! I thought all the terms were "standard" --- my mistake. So, translating from the context specific nature of the source, to more generalized ring algebra: "a proper ideal cannot contain any elements of the ring which have multiplicative inverses"?

Comment: I imagine "standard" terms may have other meanings in *nonstandard* analysis! Also, this paper was written by an undergrad who may have confused some definitions. Or maybe "regular" is defined that way in the references of the paper. Anyway, it's clear that the statement is not true with the usual meaning of regular. In a domain (like $\mathbb{Z}$) every nonzero element is regular, and every non-unit is contained in a maximal ideal, which is a proper ideal by definition.

Comment: @André3000 yup, I think that proves the statement they are trying to get at. I have also had a look at Loeb and Hurd (not undergraduates) who take a slightly different approach. Together, these answer my question :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quoting a different definition of “regular” than used in the paper. Note that $^*\mathbb{R}$ is a field, so there is no zero-divisor and the definition you quote applies to every element except $0$.

For the cited paper, “regular” is synonymous with “invertible”. The set $\vartheta$ consisting of the infinitesimal numbers is precisely the set of noninvertible elements in $\mathcal{O}$, because their inverse in $^*\mathbb{R}$ is infinite and $\mathcal{O}$ just consists of the finite numbers.

The paragraph you got stuck with simply says that $\vartheta$ is a maximal ideal because $\mathcal{O}/\vartheta$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, which is a field.

Comment: For a moment, I thought I was on tex.stackexchange :p

Answer (score 2):

This is not true, take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $a=p\neq 1$.